# Looking for Joomla Extensions suggestions

Tags: joomla

A colleague and I have been partnered on a project for school, in which we must take an existing site and revamp it to client specifications.

The client's site is the college journalism site, built on Joomla. They're currently using an archaic version, and we are migrating their content to a new installation. In addition to an overhaul to the interface (which we are having no trouble with) the client has asked for the addition of some features.

- Email subscription services
- Moderated social commentary
- Multimedia integration

For Email subscription services, we've decided on [jNews](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/11585?qh=YToyOntpOjA7czo1OiJqbmV3cyI7aToxO3M6NDoiam5ldyI7fQ==), and after a preliminary check on a temporary install it seems to be a decent choice. The problem we've come across is with the other two feature additions.

My question essentially is; What suggestions could SO offer of Joomla Extensions that provide **moderated social commentary** functionality, and **multimedia (audio/video)** integration, *that play well together*. I've looked at *yvComment* and *jMultimedia* for social commentary and multimedia integrations respectively, however jMultimedia breaks entirely (PHP throws an exception) post install, and yvComment is giving me headaches.

Just some quick details on the functionality;

- Moderated social commentary I suppose is rather straightforward. Something that supports perhaps OpenID or similar. Visitors can comment on articles, and moderators can review, and moderate (edit/delete) as necessary.
- Multimedia integration is also straightforward. Simply the ability to associate uploaded or linked audio/video content with articles. Gallery views, and other client side snazzyness is also important, but can certainly be sacrificed for better administrative integration.

I'm only looking for suggestions, not comprehensive installation/customization instructions, though I'm certainly not opposed to hearing any from those who have performed such tasks successfully :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used several email subscription services... I found [AcyMailing](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/10341) to be the best. Especially if you have to do newsletters often.

Moderated social commentary - [jComment](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/articles-comments/9985) is a good choice for adding commenting features to the Joomla Articles. However, I recommend using non-native version of content management like [K2](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/content-construction/8061?qh=YToxOntpOjA7czoyOiJrMiI7fQ==). K2 is extremely powerful CCK with many cook features and it comes with commenting features, social media sharing and author pages.

I used several components for videos about a year ago. The best one I found was [hwVideoShare](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/multimedia/multimedia-players/video-players-a-gallery/3698). It is a great video component similar to Youtube with sharing, commenting, etc... I'm not sure about audio.

- Subscription Service - [AcyMailing](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/10341)
- Content Construction Kit - [K2](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/content-construction/8061?qh=YToxOntpOjA7czoyOiJrMiI7fQ==)
- Video Component - [hwVideoShare](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/multimedia/multimedia-players/video-players-a-gallery/3698)

If you need community component which has Video/Images/etc look into JomSocial. That thing is amazing.

Comment: **Thanks Alex;** Great suggestions, JComment certainly looks good; simple and straightforward. My initial choices on extensions have all effectively failed in tandem, so I'm really happy you were able to suggest some alternatives. I'm not too concerned with elaborate and exhaustive features. Adding the aforementioned functionality and nothing more is likely better anyways, as my team will have to educate the editors of how to use the new features, and with migration and the other bureaucratic filler associated with this project, we're already up to our necks :P

Comment: I'm testing out your suggestions, and while I'll likely mark your answer as accepted, I'm just gonna let this sit for a bit to see what others have to say.

Comment: *jComment* and *AcyMailing* are great. *hwVideoShare* is giving me a bit of a headache, but I'll hammer through it, or opt for a different extension. Commentary and subscription were the two most important though :) Thanks again **Alex**!